# Bott periodicity for Dirac matrices?

Tags: algebraic-topology, clifford-algebras

In most of the contexts I've seen, [Bott periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem) refers to the periodicity of the homotopy groups of the manifolds of classical groups. However, recently I have heard of some physicist speaking of "Bott periodicity" as a periodicity in the reality properties of Dirac matrices, as summarized in Table 3 (page 8) in [this document](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf). 
However, it's not clear to me how the two kinds of periodicity are related. I'm looking for some explanations for this.

Comment: there is an answer at https://www.physicsoverflow.org/38854/